# WCF SOAP + REST/Json service without .svc - do I have twice the number of service factories?

Tags: wcf, rest, soap

Ok, so I wanted to have a single service exposed as a SOAP as well as REST (Json) end point. Since it's off the "WCF Service Application" template, I have a web.config and I added the following into the ...

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="MySvcClass">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MySvcInterfaceClass" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" />
            <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MySvcInterfaceClass" />
            <endpoint address="mex"  binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="restBehavior">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Assuming the MySvcClass class is implemented within \MySvcClass.svc, the above exposes ...

**Original Endpoints**

`localhost\MySvcClass.svc\` (rest endpoint)

`localhost\MySvcClass.svc\mex` (Metadata Exchange to the use the SOAP end point below)

`localhost\MySvcClass.svc\soap` (soap endpoint)

So far, so good (I think!).

Then I wanted to get rid of the ugly ".svc" seen in the paths above. So I followed this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/04/05/using-system-web-routing-with-data-services-odata.aspx) and had this in my ...

**global.asax**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MySvcClass", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MySvcClass)));
}
```

Interestingly, when I put a breakpoint inside Application_Start, VS2010 doesn't hit this particular breakpoint - even when I stop->start debugging or stop->start the IIS application pool. Bizarre! Anyway, back to the point, I can now access the services the above listed endpoints AND

**Cleaner Endpoints**

`localhost\MySvcClass\` (rest endpoint)

`localhost\MySvcClass\mex` (Metadata Exchange to the use the SOAP end point below)

`localhost\MySvcClass\soap` (soap endpoint)

**Questions**

1. Am I having TWO service factories? One from the web.config and the other from the global.asax? If yes, how can I avoid it while still having clean URLs (without .svc). I don't really need the ones with .svc in the path ...
2. I dislike cluttered web.configs, so is there any way I can move the above SOAP and REST configuration from the XML (web.config) into code (eg global.asax?) ? I know how to move the REST only end point - wipe out  in the web.config, leave global.asax as is. However doing that kills the SOAP endpoint.

**[Update]**
I had tried URL rewrites too but this killed the SOAP endpoint while keeping the REST endpoint alive. Wht I did was : Used MS's URL Rewrite 2.0 module with this in the web.config

```
<system.webServer> 
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
  <rewrite> 
    <rules> 
      <rule name="RemoveSvcExt" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url="^MySvcClass(.*)$" /> 
        <action type="Rewrite" url="MySvcClass.svc{R:1}" /> 
      </rule> 
    </rules> 
  </rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
```

However, this leaves the web app in some inconsistent state because there are some parts which still stick to the `.svc` URLs. eg: the HTML help page at the service endpoint shows `svcutil.exe http://localhost/MySvcClass.svc?wsdl` Even the WSDL at the clean location at `http://localhost/MySvcClass?wsdl` makes references to `http://localhost/MySvcClass.svc` inside it - this effectively kills the SOAP endpoint.

That's why I think ($0.02) the rewrite is just a kludge. Sigh, at this point I'm fighting with the framework to get stuff done. And it feels such a time burner ...

Answer (score 0):

For services without .svc search for file less activations in wcf
http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=188

Comment: Well, after burning some time on this answer  I can say that is incorrect. It only removes the need to have the physical .svc file; it still lives in the path itself. MSDN says "A configuration exception is thrown if you register a relative address that does not have a known extension associated with WCF." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358764(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have a REST project that as both REST and SOAP service being exposed. Now I placed an .svc file for the SOAP service to be accessed by some clients.

The below screenshot gives the folder structure of my project, the route configuration in global.asax, Output accessing the Rest Service and accessing the .svc file (SOAP service). To remove the .svc extension use the URL rewrite module.

[image: sample screenshot]

Please find my web.Config (My application is hosted on IIS):

[image: web.config]

Please find my class that implements my interface ISampleService:

[image: class]

Comment: The above way you can have both SOAP and rest. If you want to get rid of the .svc extension you can use the URL rewrite module to do the mapping.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't read the url rewrite in your web.config (image is too small). It would be far better if you could copy-paste them within the 'code' tags on SO.

Comment: Also, even if I do have the URL rewrite as
`<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="RemoveSvcExt" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^MySvcClass(.*)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="MySvcClass.svc{R:1}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>`
There are some parts which still stick to the .svc portion. eg: the HTML help page shows 
`svcutil.exe http://localhost/MySvcClass.svc?wsdl`. Even the WSDL at `http://localhost/MySvcClass?wsdl` has `http://localhost/MySvcClass.svc` inside it